# Using OpenGL on Windows Form Application in Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, opengl

I want to draw 3D graphics on Windows Form Application in Visual C++.How can I adjust OpenGL library on Visual Studio 2008? Could you advise me any tutorial that mention using OpenGl Library with Windows Form Application and Visual C++?

Answer (score 1):

[Here's](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/OpenGLViewWinForms.aspx) a tutorial on embedding OpenGL in a form application (the full source code for the demo project is also included)

Comment: Nice choice.  The tutorial is focusing specifically on how to use OpenGL with Visual C++.  It's not cluttered with details of GL or VC, just the interaction between the two.

Comment: Thanks for your help quark.But I can't work code in this tutorial.
It's building.But it can' be debugging in Visual Studio 2008.
Could you help me please?