# OpenGL with windows form

Tags: opengl, windows-forms-designer

I have a code already implemented using freeglut library for opengl. I would like to include a windows interface using windows form. Whats the easiest way to make a window interface for my project.

Comment: Just google something like "winforms opengl example".  There's plenty already written on this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using OpenGL on Windows Form Application in Visual C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187115/using-opengl-on-windows-form-application-in-visual-c)

Comment: but I already have some implementation, that thread didn't help me... I saw that one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twi things to get straight: You don't have a class implemented. you have a *main* functions that initializes GLUT, creates a window and enters a main loop. Those last two parts (creating window, doing the main loop) can not be mixed with other frameworks. If you want to use Windows Forms you no longer can use GLUT. Period, there's no way around this.

Anyway, porting code from GLUT to another framework is not hard. Follow the tutorial Nathan linked in the comment to your question to get a bare bones OpenGL window with Windows forms. Then you transplant your GLUT callback function code (display, reshape, keyboard and so on) into the event handler functions of the Windows Forms OpenGL window object.

Comment: I had downloaded the source code from that tutorial but I didn't understood it. I managed to put the windows form on that main, but it either runs the windows form or the opengl gl, maybe I need threads?

Comment: @GustavoBaiocchiCosta: You don't need threads. *You need to get rid of GLUT.* GLUT is not a requirement to use OpenGL. Remove everything containing `glut` and `GLUT` from what you have already.

Comment: if I call this method void GUI() {
 Application::EnableVisualStyles();
 Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(true);

 Radiosity::MyForm form;
 Application::Run(%form);
}

inside the main, it runs the window but doens't run the opengl window, I can run either one of the windows. I thought in putting a button that would trigger the opengl window. I am new to all of this, i find it a bit hard :x

Comment: @GustavoBaiocchiCosta: What you refer to as "OpenGL window" is probably the window created using GLUT. Like I already explained: You have to replace all the GLUT stuff with Windows Forms stuff. Somewhere in the Windows Forms code there is a Redraw handler function. You put all the code from your display call back into that redraw handler.